# how to see the mysql update insert add log

Tags: mysql

There is a table,I want to listen the update,add,delete operations,but I don't want to use triger since the performance reason,So I'm wondering is there mysql update logs,that I can get the changed row ids.
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Using Binlog should be a better way.

Here's a document for MySQL 5.5: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html